# How to use Moment.JS to convert to 12 hour clock or 24 hour clock based on timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

So I'm starting with a REALLY weird format, which is essentially the minutes after midnight represented as a number (in the timezone I'm trying to get to). So if I'm in New York and mean 6:30 AM, the starting value is 390.

Here's my code so far:

```
const open_time = (String(startingTime / 60)).split(".") // startingTime of 390 becomes an array of ['6','5']
const open_hour = open_time[0] // open hour becomes '6'
var open_minutes = 0 // if the startingTime was evenly divisible by 60, that means we're on the hour
if (open_time[1] !== undefined) { // startingTime wasn't evenly divisible by 60, need to do some calculations
    open_minutes = Number(`0.${open_time[1]}`) * 60 // get the minutes into the hour
}
const open_minutes_formatted = open_minutes.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
    useGrouping: false
}) // make sure the minutes format in 00 - 09 instead of 0 - 9 for the first 10 minutes of the hour.
const hours = `${open_hour}:${open_minutes_formatted}` // final string outputted
```

At this point, hours is formatted to something like 6:30, or if it's in the afternoon, 15:00. My question is, how do I use moment.js to format this time based on the 12 hour clock vs 24 hour clock based on where the user is?

At this point in the code, I've used the module tzlookup to get the timezone for where the user is located so I think I can use that, but not sure how the actual conversion looks. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `12 hour clock vs 24 hour clock based on where the user is?` are you saying that some locales use 12hr and others use 24hr clock as the "norm"

Comment: Yes, they do. In America it's all 12 hour clock AM/PM--In lots of other countries it's the 24 hour clock. I need to display this to the end user so it needs to make sense to them based on where they are. @Bravo

Comment: I know that, my question was trying to hint that it would be taken care of by using the appropriate locale in toLocaleString - try `en-GB` for example or `fr-CA` if you want to see a really bizarre format :p - silly Quebecois

Comment: So would I be able to do hours.toLocaleString(), but I see two parameters of importance (the first one, which is something like 'en-GB', 'en-US', etc and then the timezone parameter in the passed in options object. timezone can be passed in from my tzlookup calculation, but what about the output formatting (en-GB/US)? How is that dynamically changed based on user location? And as a side note, does toLocaleString() need a date object to work on, or can it work on strings? Can those strings be formatted like 6:00, or does it need to be the full 06:00:00, for example? @Bravo

Comment: `So would I be able to do hours.toLocaleString()` no - as you have no variable called hours, and my comment relates to Date `toLocaleString` only

Comment: Keep in mind that `6:30am` is 390 minutes after midnight on most days, but it was 330 minutes after midnight on March 13th and it will be 450 minutes after midnight on November 6th, because of daylight saving. In the other direction: 390 minutes after midnight is `6:30am` on most days, `7:30am` on March 13th and `5:30am` on November 6th.